# Initialize a sub-module within a package with SWIG and Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, swig

I have a C++ application that I swigged to Python 2.7. I'm currently trying to port my code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.4 using the Python/C API and SWIG.

I have a package containing multiple modules. The problem is I cannot find a way to initialize my module *ModuleABC* as a sub-module of package *PackageXYZ*. It works well with Python 2.7 but not with Python 3.4 (and I suppose it wouldn't work either with any Python 3.x version).

Here is my code.

### ModuleABC.h

```
extern "C"
{
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    PyObject* PyInit__ModuleABC(void);
#else
    void init_ModuleABC(void);
#endif
}

void InitModule()
{
 // Defined in the SWIG generated cpp file

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    PyImport_AppendInittab("PackageXYZ.ModuleABC", PyInit__ModuleABC);
#else
    init_ModuleABC();
#endif
}
```

### PythonManager.cpp

```
void initPythonInterpreter()
{
    Py_SetPythonHome("C:\Python34");

    Py_SetProgramName("MyApp.exe");

    #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
       // For Python 2.7 
       Py_Initialize();
    #endif

    // Init module
    ModuleABC.InitModule();

    #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
        // For Python 3.4
        Py_Initialize();
    #endif

    int nResult = 0;

    // Import package
    nResult += PyRun_SimpleString("import PackageXYZ");

    // Import module
    // ERROR: Works with Python 2.7, but not with Python 3.4
    nResult += PyRun_SimpleString("import PackageXYZ.ModuleABC");
}
```

If I change the line:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import PackageXYZ.ModuleABC");
```

to:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import ModuleABC");
```

then it runs with no error, but my module is not imported within the package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `PyRun_SimpleString` instead of [`PyImport_ImportModule`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/import.html)?

Comment: Just because I was doing some tests. Both commands give same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the problem. When using `PyImport_AppendInittab` with SWIG and Python 3 in embedded mode, you need to put the "underscore" before the name of the module, *without* the package name.

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("_myModule", PyInit__myModule);
```

Just make sure your files structure is of the form:

```
myPackage\
   __init__.py
   myModule.py
```

Then everything works as expected.