# failing to import a python module generated by swig into C++

Tags: python, c++, swig

I used swig to generate a python module that is wrapping up some C++ code:

my .i file :

```
%module module_test

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "headers.h"
%}

%include "headers.h"
```

I ran these commands :

swig  -c++ -python swig.i

swig -Wall -c++ -python -external-runtime runtime_swig.h

After building, this generated a module_test.py and a _module_test.pyd files.
The wrapper works fine in python.

Now, from another C++ project I'm trying to load this new python module, using the following code:

```
 Py_Initialize();

  PySys_SetPath(L"path_to_my_files");
  PyObject * pName = PyString_FromString("module_test.py");

  PyObject *module = PyImport_Import(pName);

  if(module == NULL)
  {
     PyErr_Print();
    std::cout << "module == NULL !!";
    exit(-1);
  }
```

However the import fails with the error :

```
 import imp
ImportError: No module named 'imp'
```

Can someone please tell me what's going on ? The module_test.py file generated by swig is doing an "import imp" in the code, but this import never failed when I run the file from python...
Do I need to specify something else so that the C++ code knows what "imp" is ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using instead :

```
PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
  PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
  PyList_Append(path, PyString_FromString("path_to_file"));
```

Comment: You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25645539/168175 which builds the module in.